# how can I inspect promises in the node.js debugger?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging

I have written an application in node.js.  In the main module, I create various promises using cujojs' [when module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/when) and push them into an array and use when.all().then() to send a happy message when they are all fulfilled.  Some of the promises are resolved when certain messages are received over a WebSocket connection.  When the WebSocket messages arrive in a certain order, I get the happy message.  When the messages arrive in a different order, I don't get the happy message.

So I want to look at the array of promises and other variables in the main module.  Simply invoking the debugger results in a "No Frames" error, so I set up a dummy "heartbeat" function that gets invoked once per second through setInterval.  Then when I set a breakpoint in the heartbeat function and tried to look at the array of promises, the debugger told me that it was undefined (should be a module-wide variable!).  So I put a `var pa = promises_array` line in the heartbeat function.  Then I tried to use when's [inspect method](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/api.md#promiseinspect) in repl as follows:

```
debug> repl
Press Ctrl + C to leave debug repl
> for( p in pa ){ console.log( p.inspect().state }
```

And it said `TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'inspect'`

So I'm not sure what is going on.  Why can't I see the variables in the module when I set a breakpoint in the module?

Comment: I'd recommend trying out node-inspector (https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Node Inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector).

Node Inspector allows you to debug your Node.js code in pretty much the same way you would debug a front-end application in Chrome Developer Tools, including using debugger statements and setting breakpoints. You can walk through your promise step by step as it executes.

Comment: This is probably a great suggestion; however, it's going to take me a while to confirm because -- minor detail -- I'm developing on an embedded platform which apparently does not currently have the entire npm ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

While it is probably a great idea to use node-inspector, it's going to take me a while to get it set up on my platform, and I just discovered that the actual correct answer to my question is I should have typed the following into repl

```
for( p in pa ){ console.log( 'marker '+p+' is '+pa[p].inspect().state ); }
```

In other words, I'm an idiot for trying to invoke a method on the index p instead of the value of the array at index p :"(